# $slider.css({'transform' : 'translateY(' + (-$height * $counter) + 'px)'})

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$slider.css({
    'transform' : 'translateY(' + (-$height * $counter) + 'px)'
})
```

I have been cracking my head on this code. Can someone please explain/break this to me in details.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i understand this code:

```
$slider.css({
    'transform' : 'translateY(' + (-$height * $counter) + 'px)'
})
```

`$slider` is a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) on which you apply css using javascript.

`$height` is a variable containing some a numeric value that stands as an height value.

`$counter` is a variable containing a numeric value. According to it's name, it is a counter value.

The whole code applies the [Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) css property to the DOM element referenced by the `$slider` variable.

if we replaced these variable by their values, we would have:

```
var $height = 5
var $counter = 3
var $slider = $(".slider")
$slider.css({
     'transform' : 'translateY('+ (-$height*$counter)+ 'px') //equals to 'transform' : 'translateY('+ (-5*3)+ 'px')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its applying style to the element in the variable slider. The style is transform css proprty and its value is translate Y calculated with multiplying negative of variable height and variable counter